# box moved when using flexible box model

Tags: firefox, css

I am trying to build a nested layout with the flexible box model in firefox.

I managed to boil it down to a simple example:

HTML:

```html
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
        <div id="content">
            <div id="scroller"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#outer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

#inner {
    border: 1px solid green;
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;

}

#content {
    display: -moz-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#scroller {

    \-moz-box-flex: 1;
    display:block;
}
```

Also I made this small jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dankurka/27GDt/1/

The problem is that the content div gets rendered about 12 px to low (as you can see from the borders in the jsFiddle). How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Add `vertical-align: top`](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/27GDt/2/):

```css
#content {
    display: -moz-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, already invested a lot of time to figure this one out :)